# What conditions on the coefficients of $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ guarantee that $p(x)\geq 0$ for some $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am working on a research level problem and I am stuck up with a third degree polynomial inequality. So I would like to know:

> Given the polynomial $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, which conditions on the coeficients $a, b, c, d$ should we impose in order to have:
>   $$p(x) \geq 0$$
>   for some $x$?

Comment: Cubics go to $\pm \infty$ at the extremes so if $a\neq 0$ you are good.

Comment: @lulu and this is a sufficient condition?

Comment: Sufficient ?  of course.  Not necessary, though.

Comment: thank you very much. Simpler than I expected.

Comment: If $a \ne 0$ then it will take both positive and negative values as lulu points out (may be tedious to "prove" that is true of all odd degree polynomials but it is).  If $a = 0$ then this will be true if $b>0$ (as it is a parabola pointing up).  If $b<0$ then this will take positive values if it's maximum value $d-\frac {c^2}{4b}> 0$. If $a=0; b=0$ then it is a linear equation.  If $c\ne 0$ this will take both positive and negative values.  If $c =0$ this will always be $d$ and will be positive if $d > 0$.  That exhausts *all* possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $a$ is nonzero, then the cubic tends to $-\infty$ on one side and $\infty$ on the other and the condition is satisfied. Otherwise, we have a quadratic; if $b$ is positive then we tend to $\infty$ and the condition is satisfied. If $b$ is negative, we require at least one root to satisfy the condition, i.e. the discriminant is nonnegative. If $b=0$, then if $c$ is nonzero we clearly satisfy the condition with a linear function. Finally, if $a = b = c = 0$ then $d \ge 0$ trivially works.

Comment: thank you so much for such a so well elaborated answer, I will accept it as long as the MSE allows me.

Answer (score 1):

This is always true. If $a>0$ then as $x$ tends to positive infinity, we’re good. Otherwise, $a<0$ (as it’s a third degree polynomial) so as $x$ tends to negative we’re good.

Comment: No it isn't.  With $(a,b,c,d)=(0,-1,0,-1)$ it is false.

Comment: that’s not a third degree polynomial like the op asks for

Comment: @Wen Just to clarify, I suggest you mention in your answer that $a \neq 0$.

Comment: It the stated problem it is never stated that $a \ne 0$.  It's true that the standard definition of a $n$-degree polynomial would state that the $n$-degree coefficient is non-zero (and all higher degrees are $0$) but in the problem it never states that it *is* a third degree polynomial.  One can take it to absurd degrees that if $a=0$ it will always take a positive value if 1) $b>0$ 2)$b<0$ and $d-\frac{c^2}{4a}>0$ 3)$b=0$ and $c\ne 0$ or 4) $b=c$ and $c=0$ and $d> 0$ and it will be never positive in all other cases.  But that's probably way overkill.